# NumPy polydiv, several variables

Tags: python, numpy

I need to divide a polynomial by a polynomial in **NumPy**. For this I use **numpy.polydiv** but in the example of the documentation of polynomials with only one variable. And I need to divide polynomials with three variables. Please tell me how to do it.

For example: x^3 + y^3 + z^3 divided by x^ 2 + z

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you use [sympy](http://sympy.org/en/index.html), which allows for basic symbolic manipulation. In your example `x^3 + y^3 + z^3` is not divisible by `x^ 2 + z`, so nothing will help you there! But, with a simple example like, `x**2 - y**2` divided by `x - y`, we can see `sympy` in action:

```
>>> import sympy
>>> x, y = sympy.symbols('x y')
>>> sympy.simplify((x**2 - y**2) / (x - y))
x + y
```